# Create a link with a router parameter

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I angular1 I created a link with an ID Parameter like:

```
<a href="rbac/role/{{role.id}}/edit">edit</a>
```

In angular2, I've tried

```
<a [routerLink]="['rbac/role/{{role.rid}}/edit']">edit</a>
```

but get the error:

> Parser Error: Got interpolation ({{}}) where expression was expected
>   at column 12 in [['rbac/role/{{role.rid}}/edit']] in
>   RolesViewComponent@18:23

How do I setup this link without calling a function of the Component to create it?

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't be using `{{}}` interpolation inside `routerLink` directive, you need to make a slight change like below. Separate it with part, expression part will evaluate inside component context(`this`) & thereafter all will get join with `/` to form the URL.

```
<a [routerLink]="['rbac/role', role.rid, 'edit']">edit</a>
```

Comment: @JoshuaKissoon look at my small update in answer, Thanks :-)